# Python ssl: why do I need to pass peer crt as ca?

Tags: python, sockets, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

I'm familiarizing myself with openssl in Python with a simple socket server/client using self signed certificates. One detail is baffling me.
I have created a CA certificate, which I used to self sign certificate csr's generated for server and client using x509.
When using the resulting certificates and private keys in the server and client I noticed that each peer needs to use the other peer's crt as cafile in create_default_context() in order not to get a *self signed* error. For example, the client uses the server's crt as ca in create_default_context() and then its own crt and key in load_cert_chain().
Since both peers' crt's are signed using the same ca crt, I would have thought they needed that ca crt as cafile for create_default_context(), not the other peer's crt. But if I use the common ca crt, I instead get the no shared cipher error. Why is that?

**To reproduce**

*Certificate creation*

1)CA:

```
openssl genrsa -aes256 -passout pass:changeme -out ca.pass.key 4096
openssl rsa -passin pass:changeme -in ca.pass.key -out ca.key
openssl req -new -x509 -days 365 -key ca.key -out ca.crt
```

2)client and server (where "user" is client or server):

```
openssl genrsa -aes256 -passout pass:changeme -out user.pass.key 4096
openssl rsa -passin pass:changeme -in user.pass.key -out user.key
openssl req -new -key user.key -out user.csr
openssl x509 -CAcreateserial -req -days 365 -in user.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -out user.crt
```

*echo_client.py*

```
import socket, ssl

server = ("127.0.0.1", 1234)
ssl_context = ssl.create_default_context(
    ssl.Purpose.SERVER_AUTH,
    cafile='ca.crt'
    )
ssl_context.load_cert_chain(
    certfile='client.crt',
    keyfile='client.key'
)

with socket.socket(
    socket.AF_INET,
    socket.SOCK_STREAM
    ) as session:
    with ssl_context.wrap_socket(session, server_side=False, server_hostname=server[0]) as secure_session:
        secure_session.connect(server)
        while True:
            data = bytes(input("Enter message:\n"), "ASCII")
            secure_session.sendall(data)
            echo = secure_session.recv(1024)
            print(f"Echo: {echo}")
```

*echo_server.py*

```
import socket, ssl, sys

def main(PORT_NUMBER):
    ssl_context = ssl.create_default_context(
        ssl.Purpose.CLIENT_AUTH,
        cafile='ca.crt'
        )
    ssl_context.load_cert_chain(
        certfile='server.crt',
        keyfile='server.key'
    )
    ssl_context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM, 0) as socket_fd:
        try:
            socket_fd.bind(("", PORT_NUMBER))
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Unable to bind base socket. Reason:\n{e}")
            return(-1)
        
        socket_fd.listen(5)

        with ssl_context.wrap_socket(socket_fd, server_side=True) as secure_socket_fd:
            session_fd, client = secure_socket_fd.accept()
            with session_fd:
                print(f"Echoing {client}:")
                while True:
                    try:
                        buffer = session_fd.recv(16)
                    except ConnectionResetError:
                        try:
                            session_fd.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
                        except:
                            pass
                        else:
                            print("Client closed the connection\nSession shutdown successful...")
                        break
                    print(f"Message received!\n{buffer}")
                    session_fd.sendall(buffer)
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        print("Must pass an address!\nExiting...")
        sys.exit(-1)
    else:
        PORT_NUMBER = int(sys.argv[1])
        sys.exit(main(PORT_NUMBER))
```

This configuration produces these errors:

-Client:
*ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate (_ssl.c:1123)*

-Server:
*ssl.SSLError: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_UNKNOWN_CA] tlsv1 alert unknown ca (_ssl.c:1056)*

If I use server.crt as `cafile` in **client.py's** `ssl.create_default_context()` and client.crt as `cafile` in **server.py's** `ssl.create_default_context()`, then the handshake is successful.

Please note that I have already tried concatenating the CA to the server and client crt's per Python's ssl guidelines.

Comment: Based on your description only this should not be the case, so probably important details from your description are missing. Please provide a way for others to actually reproduce your problem, so one can help you. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You are absolutely right, I updated the question with full context. Sorry!

Comment: Just coming back to this to see if anyone had a chance to check the added context above.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue. If I generate the certificates as described and use it it succeeds for me (assuming that CN in server certificate matches what is used by client). But, the generated certificates might depend on the openssl config and the values you enter. So in order to be reproducible please provide the generated \*.crt und \*.key

Answer (score 0):

I solved it: the problem was that the Common Name for the CA was the same as the common name for the Server. Once I recreated the certs using different common names for CA and Server it worked. I believe that might be because having the same Common Name (and therefore not a unique identifier for CA vs Subjects) broke the resolving of the cert chain.

Comment: I would also add that this now does not require the Subject certs to be concatenated with the CA. Which is consistent with what Python ssl docs say, since the self signed CA is a root cert, so once it's passed to create_default_context(), it is loaded in the trusted store as a root cert, therefore it does not need to be concatenated. Thanks @Steffen Ullrich for the pointers!